# mysql_row returning assignment from incompatible pointer type ? in C

Tags: mysql, c

folks,

see following code :

```
 gboolean auto_refresh_host_list(bahan *unit)
    {
//assuming unit->setting->handle_conn has initiated and connected
mysql_query(unit->setting->handle_conn,"select * from host");
unit->setting->handle_result = mysql_store_result(unit->setting->handle_conn);

guint num_fields = mysql_num_fields(unit->setting->handle_result);

line:148 while((unit->setting->handle_row = mysql_fetch_row(unit->setting->handle_result)))
{
    guint i;
    for(i=0; i<= num_fields; i++)
    {
    line:153    printf("%s", (unit->setting->handle_row[i] ? unit->setting->handle_row[i] : "NULL" ));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
mysql_free_result(unit->setting->handle_result);
line:158}
```

but once i compiling it show warning like these :

```
main.c:148: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
main.c:153: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
main.c:153: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘void * const’
main.c:158: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

anyway the structure suppose to be look like following :

```
MYSQL *handle_conn;
MYSQL_RES *handle_result;
MYSQL_ROW *handle_row;
MYSQL_FIELD *handle_field;
```

im a little confused after read http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/, well, anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row()` returns a `MYSQL_ROW`, not a `MYSQL_ROW *`.